# vbox disappearing inside hbox

Tags: tex-core, plain-tex

I don't understand why a vbox disappears when it's surrounded by two `\hss`, for instance in:

```
\hbox to 0pt{\hss abc\hss}
\hbox to 0pt{\hss\vtop{def}\hss}% doesn't work
\hbox to 0pt{\vtop{ghi}\hss}% works 
\bye
```

which more or less corresponds to what I'd like to achieve, why doesn't `def` show up?

There must be something obvious I'm missing here, but I can't see what. I will work around this by using some `\raise`, but I'd like to understand...

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436)

Comment: It *is* there, but rather far away! Remember that `def` starts horizontal mode and the resulting box will be `\hsize` wide.

Comment: My warm welcome too!

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The `\vtop` box will be `\hsize` wide, so it disappears beyond the left margin.

Try with

```
\hbox to0pt{\hss\vtop{\hsize=4cm def}\hss}
```

and you'll see it appear in the left margin.

Let's do

```
\hbox to 0pt{\hss\vtop{def}\hss}\showlists
```

and the log will show

```
### vertical mode entered at line 0
### current page:
\glue(\topskip) 3.05556
\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x0.0, glue set - 234.8775fil
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
.\vbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499
..\hbox(6.94444+0.0)x469.75499, glue set 436.6994fil
...\hbox(0.0+0.0)x20.0
...\tenrm d
...\tenrm e
...\tenrm f
...\penalty 10000
...etc.
.\glue 0.0 plus 1.0fil minus 1.0fil
total height 10.0
 goal height 643.20255
prevdepth 0.0
```

Comment: I understand now, thank you very much! I thought the vbox would be 0pt wide (and thus overfull)... But I should have noticed that the last box is not overfull!

Comment: @ElieRoux An `\hbox` with `\hss` in it will be never overfull nor underfull.